# Storage limit of 2-level mapping

Tags: solidity

I know that you can have up to 2^256 entries in a single mapping.

However, if I am creating a `mapping(address => mapping(uint => uint))`, then does it mean that the inner mapping can also contain 2^256 entries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a 2-dimensional mapping `mapping(uint256 => mapping(uint256 => uint256)) m;`

You *could* insert 2<sup>256</sup> values into `m[0][0], m[0][1], ..., m[0][2 ** 256 - 1]`. But there are “only” 2<sup>256</sup> storage slots in the EVM, so if you proceeded to insert a further 2<sup>256</sup> values into `m[1][0], m[1][1], ..., m[1][2 ** 256 - 1]`, they would overwrite all the others.

Multi-dimensional mappings are just an illusion. When you access `m[k1][k2]`, Solidity translates it into `slot[f(k1, k2)]`<sup>†</sup>. So all 2<sup>256</sup> × 2<sup>256</sup> = 2<sup>512</sup> possible combinations of `k1 X k2` will have to map onto 2<sup>256</sup> storage slots, so there are going to be many dogs for the same bone, so to speak. The good news is that 2<sup>256</sup> is such an inconcievably large number that the probability of accessing two mapping values whose storage slots collide is inconcievably small, so in practice the illusion will never be broken and you don’t need to worry about it.

---

† `f(k1, k2) = keccak256(k2 . keccak256(k1 . p))`, where `p` is 0 if the `mapping` is declared as the first storage variable, 1 if second, etc. More info in the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/internals/layout_in_storage.html#mappings-and-dynamic-arrays).